# Disable Previous Dates in Datepicker with Javascript

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I Am Kinda New in Javascript and I want to Disable Previous Dates from Today
I used this code to display Datepicker

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="leaveTo" name="leaveTo" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" style="width:fit-content;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right, you need to make some dates to be unselectable.

That can be done by using max, min attributes.

For more information take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Additional_attributes

```html
<input type="date" min="2020-12-23">
```

Comment: Can You please explain this in detail because this is kind of Static Method.

Comment: Hi Jaspereet, you dont need any method for this solution! you just add "min" attribute to your input. like: <input type="date" min=".." ...

Comment: The full description of the min, max is already in the link provided with the solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#max